# two different intermediate logics whose intersection is Int

Tags: modal-logic, intuitionism

Call a partial order $\mathcal{F}=(F, \leq)$ *rooted* if there is an element $a \in F$  such that for any $b \in F$, $a\leq b$.

Let $\mathcal{F}_0$ and $\mathcal{F}_1$ be two different **finite rooted** partial orders and then they could be regarded as two Kripke frames. $\textbf{F}_0$ and $\textbf{F}_1$ denote the intermediate logics of $\mathcal{F}_0$ and $\mathcal{F}_1$.

It is obvious that $\textbf{Int}\in \textbf{F}_0$ and $\textbf{Int}\in \textbf{F}_1$, my question is

> Is it possible to have $\textbf{Int}=\textbf{F}_0\cap \textbf{F}_1$
> for some $\mathcal{F}_0$ and $\mathcal{F}_1$.

Comment: No. **Int** is not complete w.r.t. a finite set of finite frames (aka tabular).

Comment: Even better, the disjunction property of **Int** implies that it is not the intersection of finitely many intermediate logics strictly containing **Int** (irrespective of whether they are tabular).